# Mathematical Model of Drones

Tags: quadcopters, recommendations, resources, online-resources

I have recently decided to take up a small project at my University involving ML techniques and UAVs. TO get started, I have been looking for *mathematical model* of UAVs, but a lot of places offer a lot of different answers. As a total beginner, I can't decide between them, can you please give me an outlook on the why, what and how of modelling UAVs? Besides, I would be really grateful if you could provide resources/links to this.

Comment: What kind of model are you referring to? :) "Mathematical model" is such a non-specific phrase in the scientific/engineering field that it has close to no meaning without clarification about what the model should include or do.

Comment: Basically, I am looking for the equations that describe the dynamics of a quadcopter, like a set of differential equations with physical parameters. The purpose of the project will involve path-following. That's how much ik so far, it'd be really great if you could guide me ahead! Thank you so much for taking the time! :)